# Regex underscore behind hyphen

Tags: regex

I have a regex to remove all except alphanumeric characters from a string (and I allow also some special characters).

My regex looks like this `[^a-zA-Z0-9() _.,-]+` It works great ([example](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/353)), but I accidentally changed it to this `[^a-zA-Z0-9() .,-_]+` and it suddenly stopped working. I moved underscore at the end behind the hyphen. And now it does not match ([example](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/354)).

What's the reason it does not work with underscore at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the underscore at the end that's the problem, it's the literal `-` that *isn't* at the end that is causing you issues...

If you escape the `-` that you want to be a literal `-` (i.e: not a range like `[a-z]`) with `\-`, then it works fine.

[Try it out](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/355):

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9() .,\-_]+
```

With `[,-_]` you are specifying a range, much like `[a-z]`... It matches everything between `,` and `_` in ASCII which includes some symbols as well as numbers and the uppercase alphabet.

[See here](https://regex101.com/r/5qEWjF/1).

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot that - is a literal